# What is making my CSS break up when I zoom out or in?

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a small web app and the layout breaks up whenever I zoom in or out. I've tried numerous solutions posted on the web and on the forum including using em instead of px units in my css. That did not solve the issue, as the picture below shows.
[My Board breaks when I zoom in or out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uflF2.png)

I'd like for the board to look like this on both small and large screens: [How The Board Should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kMcD.png)

I'm guessing the problem is with how I have positioned elements, but beyond having a slight idea of where the problem might be, I'm stumped. Can someone point out what might be causing the issue?

Here's the HTML and CSS I'm working with.

```css
.container-fluid{
    min-width: 1366px;
    max-width: 2048px;
    margin: 0px auto; 
    width: 100%;
}

.brow1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 3.125em;
    left: 29.375em;
    float: right;
}

.brow1>div {
    border-right:3px solid #328adb;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.739);
    position:relative;
}

.brow2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 3.125em;
    right: 3.438em;
}

.brow2>div {
    border-bottom:0.188em solid #328adb;
    margin-bottom: 0.250em;
    display: block;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.739);
    position:relative;
}

.brow3 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 8.125em;
    right: 3.438em;
}

.brow3>div {
    border-left:3px solid #328adb;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.739);
    position:relative;
}

.brow4 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 7.813em;
    left: 29.375em;
}

.brow4>div {
    border-top:0.188em solid #328adb;
    margin-bottom: 0.313em;
    display: block;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.739);
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="brow1">
            <div id="tile_1" class="">1</div>
            <div id="tile_2" class="">2</div>
            <div id="tile_3" class="">3</div>
            <div id="tile_4" class="">4</div>
            <div id="tile_5" class="">5</div>
            <div id="tile_6" class="">6</div>
            <div id="tile_7" class="">7</div>
            <div id="tile_8" class="">8</div>
            <div id="tile_9" class="">9</div>
            <div id="tile_10" class="">10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="brow2">
            <div id="tile_11" class="">11</div>
            <div id="tile_12" class="">12</div>
            <div id="tile_13" class="">13</div>
            <div id="tile_14" class="">14</div>
            <div id="tile_15" class="">15</div>
        </div>
        <div class="brow3">
            <div id="tile_25" >25</div>
            <div id="tile_24" >24</div>
            <div id="tile_23" >23</div>
            <div id="tile_22" >22</div>
            <div id="tile_21" >21</div>
            <div id="tile_20" >20</div>
            <div id="tile_19" >19</div>
            <div id="tile_18" >18</div>
            <div id="tile_17" >17</div>
            <div id="tile_16" >16</div>
        </div>
        <div class="brow4">
            <div id="tile_30" >30</div>
            <div id="tile_29" >29</div>
            <div id="tile_28" >28</div>
            <div id="tile_27" >27</div>
            <div id="tile_26" >26</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1920px)" href="style.css">
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve - what is is supposed to look like on both big and small screens? Also is this a fixed width or are you looking for a responsive solution where the numbered blocks get bigger & smaller with the screen?

Comment: I suspect fixed position. Can't confirm since I'm on mobile

Comment: I would expect answers to @FluffyKitten's comment before we can proceed to help you out.

Comment: @FluffyKitten II was going for a fixed width, and only resulted to a responsive solution after reading through some solutions on SO. Let me upload an image of how it is supposed to look like in the main question.

Comment: @NFL I just answered FluffyKitten, I hope that clarifies things a bit better. And you're right Sagar V, I was going for a fixed position at the onset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want elements to appear in a specific position, then you are best to use `position:absolute` - you can places things exactly where you want them. This isn't used very often in responsive websites, but your requirements are for a fixed-width display so in this case it is perfect for you.

1. You can create a container that has `position:relative` - that means that the elements we place inside it are relative to it - i.e. they are contained within it and all positions are relative to inside that container.
2. Then for your element, you use `position:absolute` and place them exactly where you want with `top`, `left` etc.
3. Now you can place the new container (I gave it the class `brow-container` in the example below) wherever you want it to be, and all of the elements will move as a single unit instead of having to measure the position of each one separately.

**Working example**:
FYI I have removed the min-width from `.container-fluid` so you can see it in the snippet window:

```css
.container-fluid {
  max-width: 2048px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.brow-container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 290px;
  position: relative;
}

.brow1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.brow1>div {
  border-right: 3px solid #328adb;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.739);
  position: relative;
}

.brow2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.brow2>div {
  border-bottom: 0.188em solid #328adb;
  margin-bottom: 0.250em;
  display: block;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.739);
  position: relative;
}

.brow3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
}

.brow3>div {
  border-left: 3px solid #328adb;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.739);
  position: relative;
}

.brow4 {
  position: absolute;
  top:40px;
  left: 0;
}

.brow4>div {
  border-top: 0.188em solid #328adb;
  margin-bottom: 0.313em;
  display: block;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.739);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="brow-container">

    <div class="brow1">
      <div id="tile_1" class="">1</div>
      <div id="tile_2" class="">2</div>
      <div id="tile_3" class="">3</div>
      <div id="tile_4" class="">4</div>
      <div id="tile_5" class="">5</div>
      <div id="tile_6" class="">6</div>
      <div id="tile_7" class="">7</div>
      <div id="tile_8" class="">8</div>
      <div id="tile_9" class="">9</div>
      <div id="tile_10" class="">10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="brow2">
      <div id="tile_11" class="">11</div>
      <div id="tile_12" class="">12</div>
      <div id="tile_13" class="">13</div>
      <div id="tile_14" class="">14</div>
      <div id="tile_15" class="">15</div>
    </div>
    <div class="brow3">
      <div id="tile_25">25</div>
      <div id="tile_24">24</div>
      <div id="tile_23">23</div>
      <div id="tile_22">22</div>
      <div id="tile_21">21</div>
      <div id="tile_20">20</div>
      <div id="tile_19">19</div>
      <div id="tile_18">18</div>
      <div id="tile_17">17</div>
      <div id="tile_16">16</div>
    </div>
    <div class="brow4">
      <div id="tile_30">30</div>
      <div id="tile_29">29</div>
      <div id="tile_28">28</div>
      <div id="tile_27">27</div>
      <div id="tile_26">26</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great @FluffyKitten! How do I mark this as the answer?

Comment: Glad it works! If you need to adjust the placement, you can play around with the container height & width and top, left etc. positions. You can mark it as the answer by clicking the grey checkmark to the left of the question (underneath the up/down arrows with the number) :)

Comment: That's what I did and the game works like a dream! Thank you @FluffyKitten! You've added to my learning experience! I struggled with this for a good day or two! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this fairly elegantly with a combination of `position: absolute`, `display: flex`, and `flex-direction`.

Note that the tiles are in ascending order in the markup. The CSS uses `flex-direction: column-reverse` and `flex-direction: row-reverse` to reverse them for the bottom row (16-25) and right column (26-30).

I'm specifying the tile size and edge color via CSS variables, aka [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*), so if you need a different size or color you can change it in a single place and the entire board will adapt accordingly.

This example omits some of your CSS in the interest of clarity--showing only what's necessary to achieve the layout.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* padding grows inward, doesn't inflate the element */
}

.brow-container {
  --tile-size: 4rem; /* establish the tile size */
  --edge-color: #328adb; /* establish the border color */
  --edge-size: 3px; /* establish the border size */
  
  position: relative; /* establish the positioning context for absolute elements */
  width: calc(var(--tile-size) * 12); /* board size based on tile size */
  height: calc(var(--tile-size) * 7);
  margin: 0 auto; /* center horizontally */
}

.brow-container .brow {
  display: flex; /* place tiles in a non-wrapping row or column */
}

.brow > * { /* all tiles */
  height: var(--tile-size);
  width: var(--tile-size);
  flex: 0 0 var(--tile-size); /* don't grow or shrink */
  box-shadow: var(--edge-size) 0 0 0 var(--edge-color); /* border on the right */
  display: flex; /* flex makes it easy to center content on both axes. in this case you could get away with text-align: center */
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0.5em; /* keep content off the borders */
}

.brow2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  flex-direction: column; /* vertical */
}

.brow2 > * {
  box-shadow: 0 var(--edge-size) 0 0 var(--edge-color); /*bottom border */
}

.brow3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  flex-direction: row-reverse; /* horizontal in reverse order */
}

.brow3 > * {
  box-shadow: calc(var(--edge-size) * -1) 0 0 0 var(--edge-color); /* left border */
}

.brow4 {
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column-reverse; /* vertical in reverse order */
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.brow4 > * {
  box-shadow: 0 calc(var(--edge-size) * -1) 0 0 var(--edge-color); /* top border */
}
```

```html
<div class="brow-container">
  <div class="brow brow1">
    <div id="tile_1" class="">1</div>
    <div id="tile_2" class="">2</div>
    <div id="tile_3" class="">3</div>
    <div id="tile_4" class="">4</div>
    <div id="tile_5" class="">5</div>
    <div id="tile_6" class="">6</div>
    <div id="tile_7" class="">7</div>
    <div id="tile_8" class="">8</div>
    <div id="tile_9" class="">9</div>
    <div id="tile_10" class="">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="brow brow2">
    <div id="tile_11" class="">11</div>
    <div id="tile_12" class="">12</div>
    <div id="tile_13" class="">13</div>
    <div id="tile_14" class="">14</div>
    <div id="tile_15" class="">15</div>
  </div>
  <div class="brow brow3">
    <div id="tile_16">16</div>
    <div id="tile_17">17</div>
    <div id="tile_18">18</div>
    <div id="tile_19">19</div>
    <div id="tile_20">20</div>
    <div id="tile_21">21</div>
    <div id="tile_22">22</div>
    <div id="tile_23">23</div>
    <div id="tile_24">24</div>
    <div id="tile_25">25</div>
  </div>
  <div class="brow brow4">
    <div id="tile_26">26</div>
    <div id="tile_27">27</div>
    <div id="tile_28">28</div>
    <div id="tile_29">29</div>
    <div id="tile_30">30</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Super! Thanks for this! I'll also implement this just to learn how it works! Thank you again!